# Just mark 1 checkbox of each question and save answer of each position - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Good morning, community, I have the following case, I have 1 list of questions with their respective YES/NO answers, which are the checkboxes, what is complicating me is how I can apply 1 validation that only allows marking 1 answer (yes or no), in turn save that answer with its respective position and then save it in a DB.

**this is my adapter(preusoadapter.kt)**

```
class preusoadapter(
                private val context : Context,
                private val listpreguntaspreuso: ArrayList<epreguntas>
                ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<preusoadapter.PreUsoViewHolder>() {

 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PreUsoViewHolder {
     val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
     return PreUsoViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_estructura_listapreuso, parent, false)
     )
 }

 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreUsoViewHolder, position: Int) {
     val item = listpreguntaspreuso[position]
     holder.render(item)
     holder.displayChecked(item.answer)


     if (position == 2) {
         holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.IVSS, Answer.DSS))
     } else if (position == 6) {
         holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.FRESERV, Answer.FREDMANO))
     } else if (position == 14) {
         holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.NA, Answer.SI, Answer.NO))
     } else if (position == 18) {
         holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.NA, Answer.SI, Answer.NO))
     } else if (position == 22) {
         holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.NA, Answer.SI, Answer.NO))
     } else if (position == 25) {
         holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.NA, Answer.SI, Answer.NO))
     }

 }
 override fun getItemCount(): Int = listpreguntaspreuso.size

//CLASE INTERNA PREUSOVIEWHOLDER//
 inner class PreUsoViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
     val binding = ActivityEstructuraListapreusoBinding.bind(view)

     private val idpregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtidpregunta)
     private val numeropregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtnumeropregunta)
     private val pregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtpreguntas)
     private val imgestado = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icosemaforo)


     fun render (epreguntas: epreguntas){
         idpregunta.text = epreguntas.id_pregunta
         numeropregunta.text = epreguntas.num_pregunta
         pregunta.text = epreguntas.pregunta
         Glide.with(imgestado.context).load(epreguntas.icono_estado).into(imgestado)


     }

     private val checkboxAnswers = mapOf(
         binding.chbksi to Answer.SI,
         binding.chbkno to Answer.NO,
         binding.chbkna to Answer.NA,
         binding.chbkIVSS to Answer.IVSS,
         binding.chbkDSS to Answer.DSS,
         binding.chbkFSERV to Answer.FRESERV,
         binding.chbkfmano to Answer.FREDMANO
     )

     init {

         // set the listener on all the checkboxes
         checkboxAnswers.keys.forEach { checkbox ->
             checkbox.setOnClickListener { handleCheckboxClick(checkbox) }
         }
     }
         // A function that handles all the checkboxes
         private fun handleCheckboxClick(checkbox: CheckBox) {
             // get the item for the position the VH is displaying
             val item = listpreguntaspreuso[adapterPosition]
             // update the item's checked state with the Answer associated with this checkbox
             // If it's just been -unchecked-, then that means nothing is checked
             checkboxAnswers[checkbox]?.let { answer ->
                 item.answer = if (!checkbox.isChecked) null else answer
                 // remember to notify the adapter (so it can redisplay and uncheck any other boxes)
                 notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)
             }
         }

     fun displayChecked(answer: Answer?) {
         // set the checked state for all the boxes, checked if it matches the answer
         // and unchecked otherwise.
         // Setting every box either way clears any old state from the last displayed item
         checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
             checkbox.isChecked = answerType == answer
         }
     }

     fun displayAnswers(answers: Collection<Answer>) {
         // iterate over each checkbox/answer pair, hiding or displaying as appropriate
         checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
             checkbox.visibility = if (answerType in answers) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
         }
     }


     }
```

}

**and this is my class epreguntas.kt**

```
class epreguntas(
    var id_pregunta: String,
    var num_pregunta: String,
    var pregunta : String,
    var icono_estado: String,
    var checkvalor: Boolean = false,
    var answer: Answer? = null
) {


}
```

**this is my structure i use for my recylcview**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
app:cardElevation="4dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icosemaforo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_android" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor_categoria1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtnumeropregunta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="N°"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtpreguntas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/contenedorcheck"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtnumeropregunta"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Preguntas" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contenedorcheck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                >
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbksi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                    android:text="@string/check_si" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbkIVSS"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="@string/check_IVSS" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbkFSERV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="@string/check_freserv" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbkno"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/check_no" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbkfmano"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/check_fredmano" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbkDSS"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/check_DSS" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbkna"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/check_na" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

It complies with selecting 1 box and unchecking the other, but I realize that when I check the box for question 1 (yes) another question overlaps and my question 1 is hidden, and I see that in some questions the YES/NO/ NA up to IVSS and DSS

example

[image]

Comment: You need to use Radio Buttons instead of Check Boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like *Tenfour04* says, `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup` would handle the "only one thing can be selected" functionality. (You'd need a different listener to handle its *button `id` has been selected* callbacks.)

But since you're already storing the checked state and displaying it, you can handle that yourself - you just need a way to ensure when one checkbox is checked, the others are stored as unchecked.

An easy way to do that is to store an `Int` which represents the checkbox that's selected. Say `0` for the first, `1` for the second, and a negative number for none.  Because each number represents *one* checked item, by changing the number you're "unchecking" the others.

If you want to store that in your data object (like with `checkvaloryes`) you can just do:

```
class epreguntas(
    var id_pregunta: String,
    ...
    var checkvaloryes: Boolean = false,
    var id_answer: Int
)
```

Then your checkbox click listeners just have to store the appropriate value, and in `onBindHolder` you enable the selected checkbox and disable all the others.

This is basically what using a `RadioGroup` involves too - you get a button ID when the selection changes (*-1* for *no selection*), you store that, and when you display it you fetch that stored ID and set it on the `RadioGroup`.

The automatic deselection of other buttons (in single-selection mode) is nice and convenient, but setting the current button in `onBindViewHolder` will trigger the `OnCheckedChangedListener` and you can get stuck in a loop, so you'd need to avoid that. One way is to only update your stored value (and `notify` the adapter of the change) if the current selection ID is different to the stored one.

But you can also use checkboxes and click listeners like you already are, you just have to handle their state yourself. Here's a bit of a long explanation of one way to do it, but it's partly about solving other problems you're probably going to run into.

---

I'm gonna complicate things a bit, because I feel like it will help you out once you understand what's happening - you have a few things to wrangle here. I'm just posting this as one way to approach that *store and display* problem.

First, I think it would be a good idea to define your *options* somewhere. Since you have a fixed set of checkboxes, there's a fixed set of answers, right? You could define those with an enum:

```
enum class Answer {
    SI, NO, IVSS, FRESERV, FREDMANO, DSS, NA
}
```

And you could store that in your data:

```
class epreguntas(
    ...
    var answer: Answer? = null // using null for 'no answer selected'
)
```

(You can use that enum elsewhere in your app too - it means your *answer* data is in a useful data structure, and it's not tied to some detail about your list display, like what order the checkboxes happen to be added in the layout. If you need to turn these enum constants into an `Int`, e.g. for storage, you can use their `ordinal` property)

Now you can connect those responses to the checkboxes that represent them. We could do that in the `ViewHolder` class:

```
class PreUsoViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    ...
    // create an answer type lookup for each checkbox in the ViewHolder instance
    // I'm going to use your binding object since you have it!
    val checkboxAnswers = mapOf(
        binding.chbksi to SI,
        binding.chbkno to NO,
        ...
    )
```

That `checkboxAnswers` map acts as two things - it's a lookup that links each `CheckBox` in the layout to a specific answer type, and the `keys` act as a collection of all your `CheckBox` views, so you can easily do things to all of them together.

Now you can create a click listener that checks which `View` was clicked, get the matching `Answer`, and set it:

```
// I've made this an -inner- class, and it need to be nested inside your Adapter class
// This gives the ViewHolder access to stuff inside the adapter, i.e. listpreguntaspreuso
inner class PreUsoViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    
    init {    
        ...
        // set the listener on all the checkboxes
        checkboxAnswers.keys.forEach { checkbox ->
            checkbox.setOnClickListener { handleCheckboxClick(checkbox) }
    }
    
    // A function that handles all the checkboxes
    private fun handleCheckboxClick(checkbox: CheckBox) {
        // get the item for the position the VH is displaying
        val item = listpreguntaspreuso[adapterPosition]
        // update the item's checked state with the Answer associated with this checkbox
        // If it's just been -unchecked-, then that means nothing is checked
        checkboxAnswers[checkbox]?.let { answer ->
            item.answer = if (!checkbox.isChecked) null else answer
            // remember to notify the adapter (so it can redisplay and uncheck any other boxes)
            notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
```

This relies on you using a *click* listener, not a *checkedChanged* listener, because *setting* checked state in `onBindViewHolder` (when you're clearing checkboxes) will trigger that *checkedChanged* listener. A click listener only fires when the user is the one checking or unchecking a box.

---

So now you have a click listener that sets the appropriate `Answer` value for an item. To display it, we could put another function in the `ViewHolder`:

```
fun displayChecked(answer: Answer?) {
    // set the checked state for all the boxes, checked if it matches the answer
    // and unchecked otherwise.
    // Setting every box either way clears any old state from the last displayed item
    checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
        checkbox.isChecked = answerType == answer 
    }    
}
```

And now you can call that from `onBindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreUsoViewHolder, position: Int) {
   val item = listpreguntaspreuso[position]
   holder.render(item)
   holder.displayChecked(item.answer)
```

---

The other reason for doing things this way, is I think your code to make stuff visible/invisible is broken:

```
else if (position == 14){
    holder.itemView.chbkna.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

This kind of thing won't work - all you're doing is saying "for item 14, make this box visible" - it says nothing about which of the *other* boxes should be visible, and which should be hidden. You'll have stuff randomly shown or hidden depending on which item happened to be displayed in that `ViewHolder` before. You need to *explicitly* say what should be displayed, every time `onBindViewHolder` runs.

You can do that with a similar function to the `displayChecked` one we just wrote:

```
inner class PreUsoViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    ...
    // provide a list of the answers that should be shown
    fun displayAnswers(answers: Collection<Answer>) {
        // iterate over each checkbox/answer pair, hiding or displaying as appropriate
        checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
            checkbox.visibility = if (answerType in answers) VISIBLE else GONE
        }
    }
```

Now you can easily update your displayed boxes in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
else if (position == 14){
    holder.displayAnswers(setOf(NA, SI, NO))
}
```

And even better, you could create groups of answer types associated with the *question* in the data. So instead of hardcoding by *position*, you can just pull the required types out of the *item* itself

```
class epreguntas(
    ...
    answerTypes: Set<Answer>

// onBindViewHolder
holder.displayAnswers(item.answerTypes)
```

You could even create preset lists for different types of question, like `val yesNo = setOf(SI, NO)` (or an enum) and reuse those when defining your questions - there are probably only a few combos you're using anyway!

---

I hope that wasn't too complicated, and the organisation ideas (and the benefits they can give you) make sense. A `RadioGroup` is simpler, but with the other stuff you'll probably have to deal with, I feel like this is a useful general approach

Comment: It is true that almost all the questions are affirmative and negative YES/NO, only 2 questions have IVSS and DSS answers, and 3 questions with YES/NO/NA answers

Comment: In the function (handle Checkbox Click), I understand that you indicated that an internal class has been created (listpreguntaspreuso) I must declare this or nest it in my adapter, and in the PreUsoViewHolder I must invoke it to access the properties of my adapter right, I have a problem there, I understand that the class must be declared with inner class?

Comment: I have a problem in the inner class all the inner class must be in the adapter or in the PreUseViewHolder class?

Comment: The `PreUsoViewHolder` references some stuff in your `PreUsoAdapter`, so it needs to be nested inside that adapter class and declared `inner` so it's inside the adapter and can see its functions, variables etc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html#inner-classes

Comment: I just updated the code in the question, but something strange or abnormal is happening, when I click on the answer to the first question (Yes or No), this is changed to another question and when I click again the correct question appears I am attaching a GIF

Comment: I managed to correct that anomaly, adding this line of code = else{
              holder.displayAnswers(setOf(Answer.YES, Answer.NO))
          }